# iOS - Unable to successfully post Multipart form Data to server using HTTP Post request

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am developing an iPhone app where I need to pass on the data from the mobile to the server. The data is in the form of multipart form data.

unfortunately, the form data is not hitting the server. I tried all the ways. But I am not able to find the issue in my code.  I am very sure the issue is in the client side as I am albe to hit API endpoint in the server from the Android app

The code is below

```
NSString *str;
                str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.mysite.com/ttk/rest/detail/updat‌​edetail"];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

                NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608";

                NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
                [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


                //  parameter imageData
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileimg\"; filename=\"a.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);

                [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                //  parameter mobilenumber
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobileNumber\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[mobilenumber dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                //  parameter countryCode
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"countryCode\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[countrycode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                //  parameter displayName
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"displayName\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[strusername dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                //  parameter mobileID

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobileID\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                NSString *strsa3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mobileID];
                [body appendData:[strsa3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                //  parameter emailid

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"emailid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[stremail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                //  parameter Boolean

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"onlycontacts\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[searchwithin dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                //  parameter searchby
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"searchby\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                if(Radio1Check)
                {//Context
                    [body appendData:[@"Context" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                }
                else
                {
                    [body appendData:[@"Location" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                }

                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                //     parameter show location to other

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"showlocation\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[location dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                // close form
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                [request setHTTPBody:body];

                NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
                NSString *json=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Resp string: %@",json);
```

I have set the closing boundary and tested this code many times. But the issue seems to be  hiding somewhere in the code which I am not able to find.

The returndata from the server is always Nil and is not hitting the server.. I have double checked the URL and the URL is also correct. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks for your time

Comment: Standard Cocoa convention is to pass an error to methods such as sendSynchronousRequest and then inspect the error if the returned value is nil.  That's where I would start.

Comment: @BrandonRoth - Thanks for the quick response. But the API endpoint is not invoked. The issue lies in the client code. Any idea about it?

Comment: That's why I suggest starting with the error.  If it encounters an error for any reason you should get an error returned via the error parameter.

Comment: @BrandonRoth - I tried that. What I get when I NSLog is Resp string: (null)

Comment: The code I used is   NSError *error;
                    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
                 
                    
                    NSString *json=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Resp string: %@",error);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by passing in an error object and inspect it to find out what went wrong when your returned data is nil.  This is standard cocoa convention.  The last couple of lines should look something like

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil     error:&error];
if (returnData)
{
        NSString *json=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        NSLog(@"Resp string: %@",json);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon Roth. I got the root cause of the issue.

Comment: 2014-07-01 01:28:02.316 konnectlinks[796:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x17eb7570 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17ea8270 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}  - This is the error. Anyone who is facing this issue, I hope this will be helpful